# Parse html tags and script tag in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

After parsing the json response I am getting the following content on my document. I wanted to display it in twitter widget format. I've tried http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html but it just displays the normal text. Is it possible in ruby on rails to parse or sanitize it in proper format and if so how it can be possible?

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>Lorewp: lore-der-sdrft: MY NAME IS JOHN <a href="http://t.co/*********">http://t.co/*******</a></p>&mdash; Kofi Jones (@Crazyt2011) <a href="https://twitter.com/Crazyt2011/statuses/3**********">September 12, 2011</a></blockquote> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: thanks anyways.. but it worked with the help of html_safe..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.html_safe` method to display it correctly.